# Electricity is the movement of electrons or ions?

Tags: electricity, electrons, atoms, ions

Electricity is the movement of electrons from one atom to another or the movement of charged negative particles (ions)?

Comment: Depends, in a metal conductor, it is the electrons that flow. In a semiconductor, it is electrons and electron "holes". And in an electrolyte, it is ions (both charges possible).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An electric current is the flow of electric *charge*.  But electric charge is not an entity, it is a property that must be 'carried' by a *charge carrier*.

An *electron current*, the flow of electrons, contributes to an electric current since the electron 'carries' negative electric charge.  However, an electric current is not necessarily an electron current.

The flow of ions (either positively or negatively charged) also contributes to an electric current in, for example, the electrolyte of an [electrochemical cell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrochemical_cell).

As an aside, *electricity* is not identical to electric current.  From the Wikipedia article "[Electricity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electricity)":

> Electricity is the set of physical phenomena associated with the
>   presence and flow of electric charge.